# how to test ejabberd internal and external components

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, tsung

I have 3 xmpp components  (internal and external) in my ejabberd. These components exchange stanzas (mostly iq)

I read in the Internet that for load tests I should use tsung, but how can I test if the stanzas exchanged by the components are correct (e.g. for a given iq query I get a given iq result)?

I saw that there is escalus by erlang solutions, can it be employed for this kind of testing and if so is there any resource online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Escalus description:

> "Escalus is aimed at checking correctness of XMPP server behaviour, in contrast to tools such as Tsung which are about stress testing, and don't verify correctness."

A quick introduction to Escalus is available here:

https://github.com/goj/escalus/blob/master/docs/intro.md

I've never used Escalus myself, so wait for better, more detailed answers.